# "Too many redirects" if forcing HTTPS, assets loaded via HTTP otherwise

Tags: laravel, ssl, https

I have installed an SSL certificate for my Laravel website, however when I open it as https://example.com the CSS/JS assets are loaded through HTTP. For example, `asset('css/charts.css')` amounts to `http://example.com/public/css/charts.css` and the browser refuses to load it because it's unsafe.

So I followed the answers to several SO questions to force all links to become HTTPS by doing the following:

1) added `HTTPS_ONLY=true` to .env
2) in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` I added the following:

```
if(env('HTTPS_ONLY')){
    $url->forceScheme('https');
}
```

Inside the service provider's `boot` method. However, after I do that and try to open https://example.com I get a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

This is the vhost file for the domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So there is nothing related to HTTPS in there. In example.com/public there is an .htaccess file that I looked at too but its contents seem innocent as well:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be and how I can debug this? This is all on Apache, Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Answer (score 0):

asset,url helper will following this environment (.env) value, so change it like this

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

and run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: what about using secure_asset helper ?
like secure_asset('css/something')

dont forget to php artisan view:clear php artisan cache:clear,

Comment: and also if you're already set APP_URL=https://something.com

you can remove this
if(env('HTTPS_ONLY')){
    $url->forceScheme('https');
}

since it would redirect https twice

Comment: Then it won't work on non-https embironments - I'd have to make a condition everywhere I include assets to only use the secure helper if https is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I am using this config for https redirect
the following in appserviceprovider.php

`if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
           \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }`

.htaccess in public

    
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Recently, i did found something else, If there are assets that are loading on http from external links(like an image on http:://abcd.jpg), then your page will tend to load on http instead of https.
It will get stuck in a loop because the same asset will cause the page to open on http again, causing page to go back on http and redirection will go on.

Comment: That's the same as my setup, no? You're just using a different env variable than me.

Comment: Yes exactly same it is

Comment: @jovan Recently, i did found something else, If there are assets that are loading on http from external links(like an image on http:://abcd.jpg), then your page will tend to load on http instead of https. It will get stuck in a loop because the same asset will cause the page to open on http again, causing page to go back on http and redirection will go on.